# List all wifi devices on VPN network

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, ip-address

I have an OpenVPN server on my Rasberry Pi that I have working successfully. Granted, I don't know a whole lot about networking, but, when I connect, I expect to see all devices (ethernet or wifi) that are connected to the same network as the VPN server by running the `arp -a` command. I also tried the `netstat -r` command. I don't understand why I can't resolve the devices on the VPN network. Is this even possible? - I feel like it should be and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Since I don't know much about networking, I'm wondering if I am having a similar problem to here but with the OpenVPN protocol: [Access other devices on PPTP VPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411798/access-other-devices-on-pptp-vpn)
-- This is over my head though

Answer (score 1):

`sudo nmap -sP 10.8.0.0/24`(replacing the IP address as required) works for me.

Results look like

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-06 18:49 CDT
Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.8
Host is up (0.21s latency).
Nmap scan report for 10.8.0.1
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 17.27 seconds
```

Comment: Is the ip your gateway address?

Comment: Is there a way to list available ip addresses with specifying an ip initially?

Comment: I don't know what a gateway address is. The address I used is the one I specified for my OpenVPN server in the server.conf file, on the line that begins "server".  I don't understand your 2nd question, I *did* specify an IP initially.

Comment: Sorry, I meant without*